# Weird keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I recently was given a new, shiny keyboard from Tracer but I quickly run into a problem. The thing is my keyboard shortcuts refuses to work (ctrl + alt + t ; alt + v and also alt + letter (for marking accents in non English languages) and instead they produce capital letters. Even stranger, if I plug in my old keyboard under the same system settings everything is fine. Same happens if both keyboards are connected at the same time: new one refuses to use shortcuts, old one is fine.

Thanks for help!

## Terminal response with new keyboard (ctrl + alt + t):

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10285559, (-312,171), root:(485,223),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10285894, (-312,171), root:(485,223),
    state 0x11, keycode 28 (keysym 0x54, T), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (54) "T"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (54) "T"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10285999, (-312,171), root:(485,223),
    state 0x11, keycode 28 (keysym 0x54, T), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (54) "T"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10286071, (-312,171), root:(485,223),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10286872, (94,112), root:(891,164),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 16
```

## Terminal response with old keyboard (ctrl + alt + t):

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10345696, (-306,330), root:(491,382),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10345796, (-306,330), root:(491,382),
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10346043, (-306,330), root:(491,382),
    state 0x1c, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10346054, (-306,330), root:(491,382),
    state 0x14, keycode 28 (keysym 0x74, t), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (14) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x29c, subw 0x0, time 10346072, (-306,330), root:(491,382),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

## lsusb as requested

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1a2c:002f China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

On windows machines this keyboard works fine. And yes, I'm working on 16.04- I'm fond of the old guy ;)

Comment: You can use `xev` to test keyboard signals, I'd compare the working output with the non working one and include the outputs in the question.

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: +1 for using markup, you're doing it right! Please add the output of `lsusb` executed with the new keyboard plugged in. Btw, you're using Ubuntu 16.04, don't you?

Comment: Sorry for late edit but here it is.